# Timeseries generator with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Trying to create a generator for a LSTM and am running into an error during the .fit_generator(), after I run it the error is

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 5)`

and I'm not really sure how to reshape the data when it is in a generator.

```
n_features=1
series=train_temp.reshape((len(train_temp),n_features))

generator=TimeseriesGenerator(train_temp,train_temp,length=5,batch_size=1)

model = Sequential()
model.add( LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(5, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=90,steps_per_epoch=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the shape of input vectors being generated by `TimeseriesGenerator` and compare it with input shape of your `LSTM layer`. Looking at the exception i guess your input shape should be **(5, )** and not **(5, 1)**